# PowerShell objects' methods examples

Tags: object, powershell, methods

How can one get examples on how to use the objects' methods through [`Get-Help`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Get-Help)?

And why is there a discrepancy in the number of methods listed in PowerShell and in MSDN?

For example, `'a'|gm|? name -like '*char*'` shows there is a `ToChar()` method for strings but *[String Class, Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string#methods)* doesn’t.

Comment: The `ToChar` could came from the `IConvertible` interface - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible.tochar.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is another way around. For example, you are not sure about all members in `System.String` class then to list out all members you can do below using `Get-Member` commandlet

```
$string = "hello";
$string | Get-Member
```

This will give you a rough signature/definition of the members like

```
   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone()
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB)
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)
```

similarly, to view Static members use `-Static` switch like

```
$string | Get-Member -Static
```

If you want more information on a particular member(s) then `MSDN` is always there.

Also, see this [Nice Technet Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/11/09/using-powershell-get-member-to-explore-the-net-framework.aspx)

Comment: So how would I get an EXAMPLE of how to use the `ToChar()` method ? Not sure why only this method isn't listed in MSDN.

Comment: Every method is listed in MSDN. Do you mean `Convert.Tochar()` method? Cause `System.String` class don't have any method named `Tochar()`

Comment: `'a'|gm|? name -like '*char*'`

Comment: No, unfortunately there is no built-in way to do that kind of help search. Consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.

Comment: Sure, the previous was the Powershell command you could run to see that there is a `ToChar()` method for the System.String object.

Comment: I am not sure what you are pointing to. AFAIK, there is no Tochar() defined in String class. Check MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: So the fun part is that PowerShell will impose methods onto objects that are not a part of their class. Looking at the list of methods that come directly from the [System.String], and what all is available in PowerShell to a string `'a'|Get-Member -MemberType Methods -Force` shows that PowerShell has given several methods that are not native to the class. There is no good way to figure out where they come from that I know of. `('a').PSObject` only lists String and Object as base types, and neither of those have ToChar as a method.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the [PSCX](http://pscx.codeplex.com) module, you can get to the online MSDN topic like so:

```
Pscx\Get-Help -Object [string] -Online
```

If you grab the latest version of PSCX (3.2.0), this proxy is disabled by default.  To turn it on, import the module like so:

```
Import-Module Pscx -ArgumentList @{ModulesToImport = @{GetHelp = $true}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `Get-Help` cannot be used to get help about methods on objects/classes. At the moment you'll have to resort to web searches.

Comment: Re *"...get help amount methods..."* (incomprehensible): Do you mean *"...get help about methods..."*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yeah should've been `about`, I've updated.